# Re-ordering String variables alphabetically

Tags: java, string, sorting, variables, int

Hey so i was wondering what would be an effective way of re ordering 3 different string variables alphabetically? I attempted to use .compareTo() as a way of comparing them. But became stuck and confused how to covert this back to a reordered list of strings.

```
public static void main(String args[])
{
    String a = "Can", b = "Am", c = "Be", d= " ";

    int first = a.compareTo(b);
    int second = a.compareTo(c);
    int third = b.compareTo(c);
    int fourth = d.compareTo(d);
    if (first > 0)
    {
        fourth = second; 
        second = first; 
        first = fourth;
    }

    System.out.println(first);
    System.out.println(second);
    System.out.println(third);
    System.out.println(fourth);
}
```

Comment: Is there any reason you're using multiple variables rather than just an array or list, which can be sorted easily?

Comment: put all of them in a list of string then call `List.sort()` (from Java 8) or `Collections.sort()`

Answer (score 2):

You can just put them to a TreeSet. TreeSet automatically orders it for you alphabetically.

Example code:

```
String a = "Can", b = "Am", c = "Be", d= " ";
TreeSet<String> set=new TreeSet<>()
set.add(a);
set.add(b);
set.add(c);
set.add(d);
for (String s:set){
    System.out.println(s);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

An easy way to do it would be to store the strings in an array and then sort it

```
String[] array= {"Can", "Am", "Be", " "};
Arrays.sort(array);

for (String string : array) {
    System.out.println(string);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use Collections.sort() method as follows

```
List<String> arr = new ArrayList<>();
arr.add("Can");
arr.add("Am");
arr.add("Be");
arr.add(" ");

System.out.println("Before sort : "+arr);
Collections.sort(arr);
System.out.println("After sort : "+arr);
```

Outputs :

```
Before sort : [Can, Am, Be,  ]
After sort : [ , Am, Be, Can]
```